# EL_ERROR does not fail all actions

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have a oozie job that has 3 actions A1,B1 and C1. I am running the three actions in parallel by configuring in a fork. When A1 gets failed due to EL_ERROR the job gets failed. However the status of the other two actions B1 and C1 are still in progress and they don't get completed. What could be the issue.

Comment: If one of the action has failed (in fork-join), then all the other actions also should be killed by oozie.

Comment: @YoungHobbit But it does not happen when we get EL_ERROR. The other actions still show in progress

Comment: Can you share the workflow and some logs.